# Is there an established notation for this "replacement" operation?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

If $S$ is a set, define
$$(x \to y) \cdot S := \begin{cases}
(S \setminus \{x\}) \cup \{y\} & \text{ if } x \in S \text{ and } y \not \in S; \\
S & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

In other words:

- If $S$ does not contain $x$, leave it alone.
- If $S$ contains $x$ but not $y$, replace $x$ with $y$.
- If $S$ contains both $x$ and $y$, though, leave it alone.

Is there a pre-existing notation for this operation anywhere in the literature?

Bonus question:  I'd also like a compact notation for
$$(x_1 \to y_1) \cdot (x_2 \to y_2) \cdot S,$$
if it exists.

Comment: I'm not aware of a pre-existing notation for this operation, yet for you bonus question may I simply suggest $((x)_n\rightarrow (y)_n)\cdot S$?

Comment: Entirely tangential comment: in what situation have you encountered such an operation? // @b00n I don't like your suggestion, since it does not accurately capture the meaning of case $(z \to x)\cdot(y\to z)\cdot S$.

Comment: Incidentally, in writing my previous comment I realized that a better (than what you wrote) notation would either have as prefix notation left pointing arrows, or use the right pointing arrows in postfix notation. (E.g. $(y \leftarrow x)\cdot S$ or $S \cdot (x\to y)$) This way the compositions can be read more naturally.

Comment: @WillieWong: Consider e.g.
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & t-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & t & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{t} & \frac{1-t}{t} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \cdot \operatorname{span} \{e_i, e_j, e_k \}\right]$$

Comment: There is a notation for subterm substitution, among others $[y/x]M$, $M[x := y]$, $M[x \to y]$ or $M[x \mapsto y]$, but your case is different, and for that particular reason I would create my own notation.

Comment: (cont'd)

This is equal to (modulo any typos)
$$\operatorname{span} \left[\begin{pmatrix}
e_2 \to e_1 \\
e_5 \to e_4 \end{pmatrix} \cdot  \{e_i, e_j, e_k \}\right].$$